# How do I create consecutive numbers with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing a ticketing system. Each ticket will be prefixed with a label from the project it belongs to. An example would be CARS-264.
I know I can use the unique ID MongoDB generates but it's not very useable when people enters a ticket number manually to find it.
- So, do I keep a table with the last used number for each project (this require and extra update for the number) or 
- do I find the max number used for each new ticket. 
What will be best?

Comment: Take a look at [Create and Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) in the official documentation guides. Meanwhile, the rest of us can search for a duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the sarcasm. Both were helpful.